# Javascript Regex ignore a hyphen

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a little help in how to structure the following Regex replace.  I have a string of names and I need to replace one of the names with code that wraps a bold around it.  My problem is that sometimes the name is hyphenated such as Jones-Smith.  Some times the hyphen is missing such as Jones Smith so if the string is

```
     NameString = "Green, Blue, Yellow, Jones-Smith, Pink"
```

I need

```
   NameString ="Green, Blue, Yellow, <b>Jones-Smith</b>, Pink"
```

and if I have

```
       NameString= "Green, Blue, Yellow, Jones Smith, Pink"
```

I need

```
        NameString= "Green, Blue, Yellow, <b>Jones Smith</b>, Pink"
```

I could have either

```
       thisLastName= "Jones-Smith"
```

or

```
      thisLastName= "Jones Smith"
```

Comment: What are you using currently? `replace(new RegExp(thisLastName), ...)` does not make sense, `.replace(thisLastName, ...)`  would do here then

Comment: "J. Jonah Jameson" matches "Jo Jonah Jameson"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on your purpose or reason for using regex rather than simply `string.replace('name-to-replace')`, but you could use the vertical line character for OR in regex `|`:

```
let regex = /Jones-Smith|Jones Smith/
```

Comment: Regex is from some code I inherited and I think it was copied from a Google search.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need regex for this. Try using replace with string instead.